# Regex to match consecutive n (alpha numeric)

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I am trying to match consecutive n(alpha numeric) characters in a string.

Where n = 3

```
i7g172w2n             YES (it has 3 consecutive number)

adab172cd             NO (it has 4 consecutive alpha even though it has 3 consecutive number)

aaa172afa             YES (it has 3 consecutive number and 3 consecutive alpha)

ab21cd172             YES

abc21a3d3             YES
```

Can some one help me.

Here is my regex : `(\D(\d{3})\D)|\d([a-z]{3})\d`    not working.

Comment: All of your examples have 3 consecutive alphanumeric characters. Do you mean - match only if there are precisely 3 alpha characters, or 3 digits, or both, but neither should have more than 3 consecutive characters of the same type?

Comment: Thats right "if there is precisely 3 characters, or 3 digits, or both, but neither should have more than 3 consecutive characters of the same type"  Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @JamesSapam: What language are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with following regex.

**Regex:** `^(?:(?:\d{0,3}[a-z]{1,3}\d{1,3})+|(?:[a-z]{0,3}\d{1,3}[a-z]{1,3})+)$`

**Explanation:** Basically what I have done is matched following patterns.

1. `(?:\d{0,3}[a-z]{1,3}\d{1,3})+`

   - ( `0-3 Digit` `1-3 Alphabets` `1-3 Digits` ) `<-` More than one time.
2. `(?:[a-z]{0,3}\d{1,3}[a-z]{1,3})+`

   - ( `0-3 Alphabets` `1-3 Digits` `1-3 Alphabets` ) `<-` More than one time.

Since both are in alternation, hence either of these pattern will be matched.

For string `i7g172w2n` sub matches will be `i`-`7`-`g`-`172`-`w`-`2`-`n`. Which fits into the specifications.

For string `adsb172cd` sub matches will be `adsb`-`172`-`cd`. Since `adsb` exceeds length 3. Hence won't be matched.

Similarly for `abc2p7373`, `7373` exceeds length 3.

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GqYcP0/2)**</kbd>

Comment: @JamesSapam: Looking into it.

Comment: and a11111111 also match which shouldnot ?

Comment: @JamesSapam: Please hold on for a while. It's working for alphabets. Working on digits.

Answer (score 0):

While there almost certainly is a pure-regex solution to this problem, it's going to be an incomprehensible mess involving lookahead assertions.  If you do some of the work in code instead of regex, the problem becomes much more straightforward (Python shown):

```
import re

def consecutive(s, n):
    matches = re.findall("\d+|[a-z]+", s)
    longest = max(map(len, matches))
    return longest == n

for test in ["i7g172w2n", "adab172cd", "aaa172afa", "ab21cd172", "abc21a3d3", "12a3b3b3b"]:
    print test, consecutive(test, 3)
```

Basically, it verifies that the longest consecutive sequence of digits or letters is exactly the required number, no more nor less.  Output:

```
i7g172w2n True
adab172cd False
aaa172afa True
ab21cd172 True
abc21a3d3 True
12a3b3b3b False
```