# Remove words if it has consecutive hyphens using python

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove words if those words have **two or more** **consecutive** hyphens.

Example:

```
string='20-PT-1071 PT----415 6-------ty-APR 02-FCR-TE-12 ..........'
```

From the above string, want to **remove** `PT----415`, `6-------ty-APR` and all other words with **two or more consecutive hyphens.**

`02-FCR-TE-12` also has more hyphens but they are not consecutive. So keep this in a string

Comment: Have a look at this  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex to match consecutive n (alpha numeric)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44170109/regex-to-match-consecutive-n-alpha-numeric)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need regex for this, you could achieve this through list comprehension and manipulation.

```
example_input="20-PT-1071 PT----415 6-------ty-APR 02-FCR-TE-12 .........."

output = " ".join([word for word in example_input.split(" ") if "--" not in word])
print(output)
```

Here we are splitting our input into a list of words, then filtering out any that contain the string `"--"` and finally joining them back together with a space between them.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the parts of your string and check if two hyphens are in part.

```
out = ''
example = '12-34 56--78 9-10-11'
a = example.split()
for b in a:
  if '--' in b:
    continue
  else:
    out+=b
    out+=' '
```

Comment: I assume, your string has parts, separated by a single whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Try using pattern `[\w\-]*(.\-)\1+[\w\-]*`

**Ex:**

```
import re

string='20-PT-1071 PT----415 6-------ty-APR 02-FCR-TE-12 ..........'
print(re.sub(r"[\w\-]*(.\-)\1+[\w\-]*", "", string))
# --> 20-PT-1071   02-FCR-TE-12 ..........
```